# tkinter: scrollbar appears but doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, scrollbar

Even though the scrollbar appears and it is movable, it doesn't scroll the text in the window.

I am new to tkinter and I can't seem to find the problem.

This is what I have tried:

```
def opensave():
    global openname
    if saveordelete == 1:
        openname = savedname.get() + ".txt"
        my_file = Path(openname)
        if my_file.is_file():
            file = open(openname, "r")
            readopenname = file.read()
            file.close()
            root = Tk()
            root.title("Saved file")
            root.iconbitmap("morseicon.ico")
            root.resizable(0,0)
            root.geometry("520x610")
            scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
            scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )
            T = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
            scrollbar.config( command = T.yview )                      
            T = Text(root, height=500, width=500)
            T.pack()
            T.insert(END, readopenname)
            root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want it to control the `Text` widget or the `Listbox` widget? You've assigned it to the `Listbox` but the text of your question seems to imply the `Text` widget.

Comment: Even when I assign it to Text, it doesn't scroll the text when i use it.

Comment: fix a bit grammar and improved readebility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually i managed to solve the problem:

```
def opensave():
        global openname
        if saveordelete == 1:
            openname = savedname.get() + ".txt"
            my_file = Path(openname)
            if my_file.is_file():
                file = open(openname, "r")
                readopenname = file.read()
                file.close()
                root = Tk()
                root.title("Saved file")
                root.iconbitmap("morseicon.ico")
                root.geometry("520x610")
                root.resizable(0,0)
                scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
                scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )
                mytxt = Text(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
                mytxt.insert(END, readopenname)
                mytxt.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
                scrollbar.config( command = mytxt.yview )
                mainloop()
```